# Observações nas respostas

Tags: debate

Nesta pergunta o usuário deixou uma observação:

> Obs: ainda vou editar esta resposta nos próximos 2 dias.

Vejam: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14740

Porém uma edição foi feita por outro usuário e isso foi retirado. Será que deveria?

Comment: Talvez fosse interessante questionar o usuário, mas acho que nesse caso está tudo bem, já que se passaram um pouco mais de dois dias. ;)

Comment: Eu acho que o interessante seria questionar o Cigano (que é o OP), ao invés de simplesmente chegar e editar. Eu pus um comentário no post dele logo após a edição e ele disse tudo bem terem editado, mas acho que um comentário resolveria e ele mesmo poderia ter decidido se tiraria/mudaria a frase ou talvez lhe serviria como um lembrete para aquela resposta. Conforme meu voto para rejeitar, eu acho que: "A edição é incorreta, ou uma tentativa de **debater ou comentar a postagem**". Mas ao mesmo tempo não acho que chegou a ser algo grave terem aprovado, já vi coisas muito piores :/